# Clone then Append an element from a potentially infinite list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry to bug the SO community with this, but I have to move on with my life: There is a potentially infinite list of clickable images(will be expanded in future), when clicked these images can fill up a max of two spots in separate elements. The next step in this is not only filling the next unfilled element, but if they select from the list again, then it will go back to spot 1, replacing the old image. I can't think of way to apply the right logic to achieve this. Here is what I have so far.

```
<div class="spot-1"></div><!--start here -->
<div class="spot-2"></div><!--then here -->

<div class="img-wrap">
<div><img class="PutinSpot"src="someIMG0.jpg" alt="dufuq?"></div>
<div><img class="PutinSpot"src="someIMG1.jpg" alt="dufuq?"></div>
<div><img class="PutinSpot"src="someIMG2.jpg" alt="dufuq?"></div>
<div><img class="PutinSpot"src="someIMG3.jpg" alt="dufuq?"></div>
<div><img class="PutinSpot"src="someIMG4.jpg" alt="dufuq?"></div>
</div><!--potentially^^^^^ infinite list-->
```

And here is the Jquery for it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.PutinSpot').click(function(){
    var CloneBadge = $(this).clone()        
    $(CloneBadge).appendTo('.spot-1').addClass('occupado');
    if ($('.spot-1 div').find('> img').length) {
      $(this).appendTo('.spot-2');
    } 
    });
    });
```

To clarify.
The list needs to be able to grow indefinitely. But I want it to put a clicked image from the img-wrap div, into spot-1 , then the next image clicked into spot-2, once full, have it check for whether they are both full and if so, appendTo spot-1 again. Would this be a loop? Switch case?

Comment: The divs "spot-1" and "spot-2" will have the last 2 selected images?

Comment: Infinite? Not really. What is your question?

Comment: Would max, 100 images work then, I intend to make this list pretty expansive.

Comment: What I mean by grow indefinitely is  this: I can think of a way to check for enumerated class names, but that's finite, and I don't know how many of these types of images will need to be in that list.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Elaborate on what you want to achieve, not how.

Comment: I apologize, I edited it to reflect what I want to do. Basically, how do I proceed with the logic of making the clicked images appear in spot 1(for 1st image)  then spot 2 (for 2nd image) , then back to spot-1 (if image is clicked again) They don't have to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming try to think in terms of how the the data will flow. Manipulating the DOM to achieve the final behavior is a secondary concern. Let's rephrase your problem this way, assuming I understood the requirement correctly:

> There's a variable sized list of images from which the user can select
>   a maximum count of two. The currently selected images will be displayed in 2
>   separate spots

A solution to this problem in a context where the images already are in the DOM would look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.PutinSpot').click(function() {
    selectImage(this);
  });
});

var selectedImages = [];

function selectImage(imageEl) {
  // Remove an element from the front of the array if length is 2
  // This way the array will allways have 2 elements maximum
  if (selectedImages.length == 2) selectedImages.shift();

  selectedImages.push(imageEl);

  // For each selected image, find the correct div and
  // replace the content completely with the correct image
  selectedImages.forEach(function(img, i) {
    var targetDiv = $('.spot-' + (i + 1));
    targetDiv.html($(img).clone());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Selected Image 1: <div class="spot-1"></div>
<!--start here -->
Selected Image 2: <div class="spot-2"></div>
<!--then here -->
<hr/>
<div class="img-wrap">
  <div><img class="PutinSpot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000000" alt="dufuq?"></div>
  <div><img class="PutinSpot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000" alt="dufuq?"></div>
  <div><img class="PutinSpot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffff00" alt="dufuq?"></div>
  <div><img class="PutinSpot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f110f2f" alt="dufuq?"></div>
  <div><img class="PutinSpot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0000ff" alt="dufuq?"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, so you are storing them in an array. Very nice. To make them fill in the array the opposite way, you would switch "var targetDiv = $('.spot-' + (i + 1));"  to " var targetDiv = $('.spot-' + (i - 1));" correct?

Comment: Not really. Arrays are 0 indexed, so for the first element `i` is 0, for the second it would be `1` , and so on. Using `i - 1` would result in the loop looking for divs with class `spot--1` and `spot-1`. To reverse the order use `pop` and `unshift` instead of `shift` and `push` respectively. This way new elements are stored in the front position of the array instead of the back.

Comment: I get it now, you see, I'm the design guy on this project. My partner wasn't picking up the phone, and I thought I'd take a stab at it. I've never used pop/push or shift/unshift... ever. Thank you so much.

Comment: Always glad to help!